# Using pthreads can't seem to pass a vector through the pthread_create function

Tags: c++, vector, pthreads

I get an error when trying make this function work. I'm writing a parallel merge sort function. The error is that I can't seem to figure out how to pass a vector through to pthread_create function. I can't seem to figure out how to pass in all the information about the vector so that the parallel mergesort can work and yet still convert it to a void * so that I can pass it in as a parameter for the pthread_create function.

```
`void parallel_mergesort(void * a) {`


      //std::vector<int> v = (std::vector<int>) * a;




    vector<int>* v = static_cast<vector<int>*>(a);
      int mid = v->size()/2;
      pthread_t threads[2];

      int count;

      std::vector<int> * v1;
      std::vector<int> * v2;


      int start = 0;
      int end = 0;

      for (int i =0; i < mid; i++)
      {
        v1[i] = v[i];
        start = i;
      }


      for (int j = 0; j < v->size(); j++)
      {
        v2[j] = v[j+mid];
        end = j + mid;
      }

      if (start >= end) return;

      count = pthread_create(threads[0], NULL, parallel_mergesort, (&v1));
      if (count) {
        printf("unable to create thread");
        exit(1);
      }

      count = pthread_create(threads[1], NULL, parallel_mergesort, &v2);
      if (count) {
        printf("unable to create thread");
        exit(1);    
      }

      pthread_join(&threads[0], NULL);
      pthread_join(&threads[1], NULL);


      //merge(..
      pthread_exit(NULL);


    }

int main()
{
 std::fstream infile("data.txt", std::ios_base::in);
 std::fstream outfile_pms("parallelmergesorted.txt", std::ios_base::out);



 std::vector<int> parallel_mergesorted = vals;
 parallel_mergesort(parallel_mergesorted);
 for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = parallel_mergesorted.begin(); it != parallel_mergesorted.end(); ++it) {
    outfile_pms << *it << std::endl;
 }
}
```

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with the "could not convert '& threads [0]' from pthread_t * to pthread_t." I needed to take out the '&' sign. However the pthread_create function is still giving me issues.

Comment: I would recommend that you review the sections about pointers in your favourite book.

Comment: @user3088470 Can you edit your code to post a self contained example that compiles (see http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Hopefully thats better. The one compilation error that I get however is the one regarding the pthread_create function. And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I believe there is an EU directive that requires any error message to be reproduced verbatim within initial 2050 bytes of the question. Otherwise the discussion is technically referred to as "babble".

Comment: You'd be better off using C++11 `std::thread`.  If your compiler doesn't support that, you'd be better off finding a compiler that does.

Comment: I wish I could but I can't. I'm stuck using the pthread library.

Comment: @user3088470: Why did you remove the code?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you bind (a pointer to) the argument to fourth parameter of `pthread_create`. When the thread is then started, the argument is bound to the parameter of the thread's start routine.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* start routine of the thread */
void *task(void *data)
{
  char *s = data; /* cast argument to the appropriate type */

  puts(s);
  return NULL;
}

/* entry point of the application */
int main(void)
{
  char *s = "Hello, world!\n";
  pthread_t t;

  pthread_create(&t, NULL, task, s); /* pass argument to thread */
  pthread_join(t, NULL);    

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you pass, as a thread argument, a pointer to a variable that has automatic storage duration, be careful and make sure that the variable stays in scope for at least as long as the thread can access it.